# How to change cursor style for elements in editable div

Tags: html, contenteditable, mouse-cursor

I am trying to change the cursor to "pointer" for specific elements in content editable divs.

The below html code does not work as expected in Internet Explorer 8 and 9.
Any ideas how to set cursor style for elements in editable divs?

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <img src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100430200315/fantendo/images/0/06/Foo.jpg" style="cursor:pointer"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is the `<div>` the direct child of `<html>`?

Comment: Don't think that is the problem. Edited anyways.

Comment: It's not the problem, obviously. But it's very weird to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to change the cursor for a `contenteditable` `div` (into a mouse/text caret similar to `ꕯ` to indicate that text editing and selection is possible).
The `div` also contains children `a` link elements which inherit this setting and so need to be explicitly set to the standard `cursor`.
(The example contains links to the documentation at MDN.)

```css
#edit {
  width:25em;height:4em;
  background-color:#eee;
  border-radius:3px;
  padding:0.2em;
  margin:0.5em;
  
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  
  cursor:text;
  }

#edit a {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="edit" contenteditable>
Hi, my name is <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div"><code>div</code></a> and I'm <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable"><code>contenteditable</code></a>.<br/>
My <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor"><code>cursor</code></a> style is set to <code>text</code>.<br/>
I'm also <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize"><code>resizable</code></a> and I <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow"><code>scroll</code></a>!<br/>
So I'm almost like a <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea"><code>textarea</code></a>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific element that inner in div[contenteditable=true] change the cursor, you need to changes in your div element style.
for example

/*

** 
I want to change a cursor for an image.
You need to just specify **cursor: pointer | auto | text;** in your element style.

For happen we have used different types of selectors.

*/

```css
  div[contenteditable=true]>img {
      cursor:pointer;
    }


div > img 
{
    cursor:wait;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Stackoverflow</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <div contenteditable="true">
    <img src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100430200315/fantendo/images/0/06/Foo.jpg" />
</div>
  <div>
  <img src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100430200315/fantendo/images/0/06/Foo.jpg" />
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
          http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor

               http://www.marcato.org/luke/web/cursors.html
         http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_cursor
```

Changing the Mouse Pointer

When this page loads, the mouse pointer should change to a 'hand'. A custom cursor is defined by the "cursor:" style property CSS (cascading style sheets). The easiest way to change the cursor type is to add a style="cursor: crosshair" property within an HTML tag. e.g.

Text

The following links should change the pointer after being 'moused-over'. These show a number of built-in cursor styles that you can use:

auto

crosshair

default

pointer

help

move

text

wait

nw-resize

n-resize

ne-resize

w-resize

hand

e-resize

sw-resize

s-resize

se-resize

Some of the cursor styles may not work, depending on the browser.
Custom Mouse Pointers

The following HTML code will display a custom cursor:

Text

A custom URI

The user agent (i.e. browser) must be able to handle the type of cursor. Some possible file types that may work are .cur, .csr and .ani files. The above example works in Internet Explorer for Windows, but not in Netscape or IE 5.0 for Unix.